# How can I check the value of object parameter inside StatusCode response?

Tags: c#, unit-tests

Assume we have:

```
return StatusCode(500, new { message= "ApplicationSettings is Null!" });
```

Now I want to check the `message` value inside my unit test. How should I do it?

Comment: What is StatusCode? An custom-object created by you, the object of a library?

Comment: @JoãoFarias, `StatusCode(...)` is a pre-defined method in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`